# Vue js modal won't adjust below width of element it contains

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to use the [Vue js modal example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html) at a larger size. I made the "modal-container" class 500px wide, with 30px of padding and a max-width of 80%. For some reason, the "modal-mask" class, which contains the container class, just won't adjust lower than 560px when set to 100% width. What's going on here?

To put it simple: I want a larger modal, and I want it to fit on the page at minimum widths.

```
<template id="modal-template">
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="hideModal">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'VueModal',
    methods: {
      hideModal () {
        return this.$store.commit('hideModal')
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: table;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
  }

  .modal-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .modal-container {
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .modal-header h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #42b983;
  }

  .modal-body {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

  .modal-default-button {
    float: right;
  }

  .modal-enter {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .modal-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .modal-enter .modal-container,
  .modal-leave-active .modal-container {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"table-layout: fixed" on the *modal-mask* class worked for me.